# What's the word for withholding medicine from a sick person?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard a single word before that means "withholding medicine from a sick person" or "withholding food from a starving person" or "refusing to alert an airplane pilot flying in the dark that he's about to crash into a mountain". The basic idea is not taking some action knowing that inaction will later lead to harm for another person.

I thought for sure there was a single word for this (and it's more malicious than "negligence"). What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are referring to **omission**: a failure to do something, esp. something that one has a moral or legal obligation to do.

Synonyms: negligence, neglect, neglectfulness, dereliction, forgetfulness, oversight, default, lapse, failure.

Perhaps you have heard of sins of **o**mission, as opposed to sins of **co**mmission. People have a moral obligation to do the right thing. If they *do the wrong thing*, they have committed a bad act. If they *fail to act when it is called for*, they are to blame for what they *did not do*.

Comment: That's probably as good as I'm going to get, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of [malevolent](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/malevolent) perhaps?

Comment: 'Malevolent' is far more general than what OP is asking about.

Comment: Maybe I'm just imagining it, but I thought English had a word for this more specific than "malevolent" or "malfeasance".

Comment: @AlexHenrie *malpractice* : improper, illegal, or negligent professional activity or treatment, especially by a medical practitioner, lawyer, or public official.

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of "malfeasance"? The first examples suggest "deprivation," and that, too, is malicious. But deprivation doesn't fit the case of not alerting someone.